# How to track the Web Logic Server Performance via admin console - WLS 12c

Tags: performance, export, weblogic

We have an application which is deployed on Web Logic Server. We have export functionality with requirements of exporting quite huge records
(say 50,000-100,000). We have server with capacity of 16GB. The application runs fine when single user exports the data, but we are getting OutofMemory Error when more than one user tries to export.

technology used: JSF 2.0, Prime Faces 3.5, EJB and JPA

We tried increasing the heap size for Web Logic server, that could not help.
Is there any way where we can check the web logic server performance when these exports are running. We want to find if any memory leak exists.
Any other suggestions also welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check from "Monitoring Dashbord" admin console in web logic server

Comment: I tried but it doesn't help. Its always constant :(